# Tomcat undeploys WARs automatically after some time

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm facing an issue with **Apache Tomcat 9.0.13** with **JDK 1.8**, where it tries to reload memory user database & upon failure, undeploys all the WARs of `webapps`.

Stacktrace of the exception is as follows:

```
12-Dec-2018 14:16:45.739 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Dec-2018 14:16:45.766 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-Dec-2018 14:16:45.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 11788 ms
12-Dec-2018 15:34:02.582 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Reloading memory user database [UserDatabase] from updated source [file:/P:/Tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/conf/tomcat-users.xml]
12-Dec-2018 15:34:02.582 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found
12-Dec-2018 15:34:03.082 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context []
12-Dec-2018 15:34:03.082 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Error while removing context []
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle$SingleUse
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:834)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1434)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1360)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1179)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1405)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1373)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please note, `tomcat-users.xml` is located at `conf` folder.

Can anyone help me fix the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: There was a bug with the tomcat-users.xml file. Maybe is related with your problem.  Could you run some tests with the latest Tomcat? https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62924.

Comment: @lalo, Thanks for your reply. I've looked at the issue mentioned in your link. But the issue I'm facing is different than that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server on which Tomcat is running lost the connection to the `P:` drive momentarily. That triggered both the failure to check the `tomcat-users.xml` file and the undeloyment of the web applications. You need to move the `webapps` directory to a more reliable network location or, better still, a local drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It indeed solved the issue. I'm more interested in knowing how did you come to know that `P:` is a network location & not a local drive?

Comment: Experience ;)
- Chances are P: is not local (local drives are typically earlier in the alphabet)
- Undeployment is triggered by files being deleted
- tomcat-users/xml was reported as not present
- but when you checked they were all there
It looked like a bunch of files disappeared and re-appeared. And that looked like an unreliable network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the file `tomcat-users.xml` has not been found - might be removed or corrupted. This file serves as an in-memory database for the Tomcat management users. Download the Tomcat again and add the missing/corrupted file to the `conf` folder.

Also, search for the following lines to the `server.xml` which should be included because it registers in JNDI as an instance of `UserDatabase`. If the lines are missing, add them:

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
    pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"
    description="User database that can be updated and saved"
    type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
    factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
/>
```

The conclusion and the safer way would be to download a new entire instance of Tomcat from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please read my question carefully. I've already mentioned that `tomcat-users.xml` file is in place. `server.xml` contains the lines you've mentioned by default. No one needs to add these lines manually. I've already reinstalled Tomcat several times but still I'm facing this issue.